# How to get menu item below the icon in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have given Menu Items for an Icon but i couldn't able to see `Icon` while i click on the icon. It is getting hide due to Menu item. My Objective is to show icon even when we click on the icon(Drop down is shown) as shown in this link https://codesandbox.io/s/3rmgv. In the above link, we can we see a button, when we click on button, we could see the menu items as well as the button too. Can anyone help me in getting the in this way?

Here is the code:

```
<div>
        <IconButton
          aria-label="more"
          aria-controls="simple-menu"
          aria-haspopup="true"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        >
          <AccountBalanceIcon />
        </IconButton>
        <Menu
          id="simple-menu"
          anchorEl={this.state.anchorEl}
          keepMounted
          open={Boolean(this.state.anchorEl)}
          onClose={this.handleClose}
        >
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
      </div>
```

[Here is the sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/winter-sound-byxw2)